# Why is my traefik.toml file not be read by docker-compose configuration

Tags: traefik

My goal is to protect the traefik front-end with basic authentication.

I am running Traefik version v1.4.3 built on 2017-11-14_11:14:24AM in a Docker container.

My docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --web --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8081:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ~/git/traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - ~/git/traefik/.htpasswd:/etc/traefik/.htpasswd

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my_nw
```

The section for the web frontend in my traefik.toml file looks like this:

```
 ....
 # Enable web configuration backend
 [web]
 address = ":8080"
 [web.auth.basic]
 usersFile = "/etc/traefik/.htpasswd"
 ...
```

But my custom traefik.toml file seems not to be mountet/read by traefik - still no authentication necessary for the traefik front-end.

The debug log output looks like this:

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting traefik_proxy_1
Attaching to traefik_proxy_1
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=info msg="Using TOML configuration file /etc/traefik/traefik.toml" 
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=info msg="Traefik version v1.4.3 built on 2017-11-14_11:14:24AM" 
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=debug msg="Global configuration loaded {"GraceTimeOut":10000000000,"Debug":false,"CheckNewVersion":true,"AccessLogsFile":"","AccessLog":null,"TraefikLogsFile":"","LogLevel":"DEBUG","EntryPoints":{"http":{"Network":"","Address":":80","TLS":null,"Redirect":null,"Auth":null,"WhitelistSourceRange":null,"Compress":false,"ProxyProtocol":null,"ForwardedHeaders":{"Insecure":true,"TrustedIPs":null}}},"Cluster":null,"Constraints":[],"ACME":null,"DefaultEntryPoints":[],"ProvidersThrottleDuration":2000000000,"MaxIdleConnsPerHost":200,"IdleTimeout":0,"InsecureSkipVerify":false,"RootCAs":null,"Retry":null,"HealthCheck":{"Interval":30000000000},"RespondingTimeouts":null,"ForwardingTimeouts":null,"Docker":{"Watch":true,"Filename":"","Constraints":null,"Trace":false,"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate":false,"Endpoint":"unix:///var/run/docker.sock","Domain":"docker.localhost","TLS":null,"ExposedByDefault":true,"UseBindPortIP":false,"SwarmMode":false},"File":null,"Web":{"Address":":8080","CertFile":"","KeyFile":"","ReadOnly":false,"Statistics":null,"Metrics":null,"Path":"/","Auth":null,"Debug":false,"CurrentConfigurations":null,"Stats":null,"StatsRecorder":null},"Marathon":null,"Consul":null,"ConsulCatalog":null,"Etcd":null,"Zookeeper":null,"Boltdb":null,"Kubernetes":null,"Mesos":null,"Eureka":null,"ECS":null,"Rancher":null,"DynamoDB":null}" 
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=info msg="Preparing server http &{Network: Address::80 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc420270180} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s" 
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider {"Watch":true,"Filename":"","Constraints":null,"Trace":false,"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate":false,"Endpoint":"unix:///var/run/docker.sock","Domain":"docker.localhost","TLS":null,"ExposedByDefault":true,"UseBindPortIP":false,"SwarmMode":false}" 
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *web.Provider {"Address":":8080","CertFile":"","KeyFile":"","ReadOnly":false,"Statistics":null,"Metrics":null,"Path":"/","Auth":null,"Debug":false,"CurrentConfigurations":{},"Stats":{"Uptime":"2017-11-20T07:30:10.282646542Z","Pid":1,"ResponseCounts":{},"TotalResponseCounts":{},"TotalResponseTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},"StatsRecorder":null}" 
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :80" 
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=debug msg="Provider connection established with docker 17.09.0-ce (API 1.32)" 
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=debug msg="Validation of load balancer method for backend backend-proxy-traefik failed: invalid load-balancing method ''. Using default method wrr." 
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {"backends":{"backend-proxy-traefik":{"servers":{"server-traefik_proxy_1":{"url":"http://172.19.0.2:80","weight":0}},"loadBalancer":{"method":"wrr"}}},"frontends":{"frontend-Host-proxy-traefik-docker-localhost-0":{"backend":"backend-proxy-traefik","routes":{"route-frontend-Host-proxy-traefik-docker-localhost-0":{"rule":"Host:proxy.traefik.docker.localhost"}},"passHostHeader":true,"priority":0,"basicAuth":[],"headers":{}}}}" 
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=debug msg="Last docker config received more than 2s, OK" 
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=debug msg="Creating frontend frontend-Host-proxy-traefik-docker-localhost-0" 
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=error msg="No entrypoint defined for frontend frontend-Host-proxy-traefik-docker-localhost-0, defaultEntryPoints:[]" 
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=error msg="Skipping frontend frontend-Host-proxy-traefik-docker-localhost-0..." 
proxy_1  | time="2017-11-20T07:30:10Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :80"
```

I followed the docu from here: http://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/web/#authentication

I can not see whats wrong with my setup.

Comment: Looks right on first sight to me as well. Could you share the DEBUG level log output right from the start of Traefik?

Comment: ok, I added the log output. Interesting, there are two error messages complaining about the frontend. But the frontend is working.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason why the setup shown in my own question was not working, was the 'command' entry in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
command: --web --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=DEBUG
```

This command overwrite the [web] and [docker] settings form my `traefik.toml` file.

So in case when you start traefik as a docker container with docker-compose, the `docker-compose.yml` file should not! contain any commands if you mount a custom `traefik.toml` file. In this scenario, all settings should be placed into the `trafik.toml` file.

So it works with the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - $PWD/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - $PWD/.htpasswd:/etc/traefik/.htpasswd

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my_network
```

Note that the `traefik.toml` file must be mounted into container directory `/etc/traefik/`